# File upload in visual in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there any visual for file upload , where a user can upload a file. I searched a lot. But not able to find any links.Thanks .

saw this link but getting it:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/File-Upload-in-Custom-Visual/m-p/335971

Answer (score 1):

Build a [Power App](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/) to accept the file, and embed that in your report with a [Power Apps visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual).

Comment: any tutorial on that?

Comment: Lots https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=power+apps+file+upload https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=power+apps+visual